# Sql query to Activerecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Can somebody tell me please how can I do this but without SQL, I want to do it but with Activerecord

```
     <%= f.association :user, 
         collection: User.where("id not in(select user_id from clientesusers where cliente_id = #{@cliente.id})"),
         label: false, error: false,
         input_html: {class: 'form-control input-sm'} %>
```

I mean `User.where("id not in(select user_id from clientesusers where cliente_id = #{@cliente.id})") with no SQL

Thanks for your help`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.joins("INNER JOIN clients ON clients.user_id <> users.id AND clients.user_id = #{@cliente.id}")
```